# Make parents height to 100% of absolutely positioned child

Tags: html, css, position, height, absolute

I googled a lot but didn't find a good answer.

assume parent element has two child elements: a fluid image (width: 100% of its parent) and an absolute div element. if I decide to overlay div to completely fit over image (ofcourse if the div has not much content to override image boundaries) I can. example:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
}

img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.caption{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 150, .2);

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.caption .caption-text{margin: auto; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300"  alt="">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="caption-text">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
      <p>Some random text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but otherwise if I decide to position the same fluid image absolutely to overlay the div element, heights won't meet each other and that's because:

- fluid images are flexible but they basically resize based on their ratio
- a fluid div element with text contents resizes based on its parents dimensions

**So how am I suppose to make parents height to be exactly 100% height of absolutely positioned child img?**

thanx

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. The `position: absolute` gets removed from parent's flow. Which effectively means: *"its parent behaves like it does not have it as a  child"*.

So, when you have two elements you want to overlap, you give one of them `position:absolute` (the one that should be ignored by parent) and you leave the content that *should size the parent* **unpositioned** (or with a `position` value of `static` or `relative`) (you leave it in the flow, thus allowing it to size the parent).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316130/absolute-positioned-image-not-displaying-correctly-on-mobile-iphone/54317117#54317117) for a more detailed explanation.

---

If you want to size your image based on current contents of parent, your best bet is to use it as a `background-image` on the parent. `background-size` allows it to size it accordingly (`cover`, `contain`, etc...):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x300) no-repeat center /cover;
}

.caption{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 150, .2);
}
.caption .caption-text{margin: auto; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="caption-text">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
      <p>Some random text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice I removed `position:absolute` from the content I want to size the parent (because I want it to size the parent).

Obviously you can achieve the same by still using an `<img>` tag and positioning it absolute and making sure it gets displayed under the contents, but `background` has been natively developed for this purpose, so it makes more sense to use it.

For the kicks, here's how it would look with the `<img>` positioned absolute:

a) contain:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
}
.container .positioner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.positioner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.caption{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 150, .2);
}
.caption .caption-text{margin: auto; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="positioner">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300">
  </div>
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="caption-text">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
      <p>Some random text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

b) cover:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
}
.container .positioner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.positioner img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.caption{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 150, .2);
}
.caption .caption-text{margin: auto; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="positioner">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300">
  </div>
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="caption-text">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
      <p>Some random text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, thats the thing. The position: absolute element gets removed from parent's flow. and worst it's an image. thanks. i really appreciate it

Comment: I need 2 layers for css animation purposes. I came up with this solution. I've set height: 100% on absolute image but it completely it squashes the img proportions. Maybe the only way is setting a min/max width or height for the content of the div element to maintain the img proportions

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't ask X for the answer to Y. Why don't you ask how Y can be achieved? Tell me what you want to achieve and I'll tell you how to do it. If it's too much work, I'll just set you on the right path (I'm lazy, by nature). Cheers!